# Using @Html.Raw and I see some border around my table

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

Service gives me signature value containing HTML tags like

`<html><body>..`

I need to display this on UI and the best way as far as I know is `@Html.Raw`. I am working on a confidential project that's why I need to be careful sharing it online.

I am having this peculiar issue while using `@Html.Raw`. Below is my sample code

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <input>
          My Signature<br/>
          <span>@Html.Raw(Model.MyHtmlSignature)/span>
      </div>
    </td>   
  </tr> 
</table>
```

In `Model.MyHtmlSignature` I am getting below data from service

```
<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 style='mso-padding-alt:0in 0in 0in 0in'>
 <tr>
  <td width=289 valign=top style='width:216.75pt;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in'>
<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
 <tr>
  <td width=289 valign=top style='width:216.75pt;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in'>
  <span style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:Arial'><br>____________________________________<br>
  Ziggler Warted</span>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I need to see like below on UI.

__

Ziggler Warted

[A horizontal line and in next line name of person]

When I use `@Html.Raw` and when I mouse click on my form I see some kind of border like below.

[image]

Did anybody had this problem?

**UPDATE**

We had a discussion on this and now service team is returning the signature like below and from that I extract **body** and show it on UI using @Html.Raw(Model.FormattedSignature)

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 10pt;" contenteditable="true">
    <p style="margin-top: 8px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
      <font size="2">&nbsp;</font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-top: 8px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
      <font size="2">___________________________</font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-top: 8px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
      <font size="2"> Ziggler Warted</font>
    </p>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Method to extract body from above html

```
public static string GetHTMLBody(string htmlString)
        {
            string htmlBody = string.Empty;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(htmlString) && htmlString.StartsWith("<html"))
            {
                htmlString = htmlString.Replace("&nbsp;", "");
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.LoadXml(htmlString);
                if (doc != null)
                {
                    XmlNodeList xnList = doc.SelectNodes("/html/body");
                    if (xnList != null && xnList.Count > 0)
                    {
                        htmlBody = xnList[0].InnerXml;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                htmlBody = htmlString;
            }

            return htmlBody;
        }
```

In my Model class I am doing like below

```
FormattedSignature = GetHTMLBody(MyHtmlSignature);
```

In cshtml

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <input>
          My Signature<br/>
          <span>@Html.Raw(Model.FormattedSignature)/span>
      </div>
    </td>   
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Thanks for all the help. I appreciate it.

Comment: That looks like a resizing handle, which the markup you've shown should not generate. Please update you question with enough code to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like browser-default styling of a :focus (or maybe :active?) selector.  Try a different browser for comparison and/or try adding `:focus {outline: none;}` to your CSS.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/focus/